# Calling own API endpoints in django command

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to call the endpoint of my own app in a `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand` pretty much like this with `rest_framework.test.APIClient`:

```
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + auth_token.key)

url = reverse('myurl-viewset')
res = client.post(url, data=payload, format='json')
```

The problem I have with `APIClient` is that it seems to be using its own testing database and so everything I do within my views to modify the db actually doesn't get inserted into the real database. I need to find a way to call my views/endpoints from a `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand` class `handle` function.

Using `requests` with:

```
url = reverse('myurl-viewset')
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + auth_token.key})
```

I get:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/api/myurl/viewset/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/myurl/viewset/?
```

In theory, I shouldn't be able to call endpoints this way anyways since my django server isn't started from running a `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand`. Now the question is: How can I call my endpoints directly from my views, from the command?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve my problem by using:

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from rest_framework.test import force_authenticate

view = MyViewSet.as_view({'post': 'myurl'})

request = factory.post(url, data=payload, content_type='application/json')
force_authenticate(request, user=user)
response = view(request)
```

With that, the main database is used.